# Table with conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation

I know how to use a table to create expressions, for example I can create a  table of variables $p_{i,j}$ where $i$ runs from 0 to 10 and $j$ runs from 0 to 10 by using the following code

```
variables=Table[Subscript[p,i,j],{i,0,10},{j,0,10}]
```

Now, I want to create the following expressions: $p_{i,j}*p_{k,l}$ such that $i+k=6$ and $j+l=4$. I tried the following code:

```
polynomials = Table[If[i + k == 6 && j + l == 4, 
Subscript[p, i, j]*Subscript[p, k, l]], {i, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 10}, 
{k, 0, 10}, {l, 0, 10}]
```

And I got the following output

```
{{{{Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, 
Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}}, {{Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}}, {{Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Subscript[p, 0, 2] Subscript[p, 6, 2]}}}, {{{Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}}, {{Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}}, {{Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Subscript[p, 1, 2] Subscript[p, 5, 2]}, {Null,
 Null, Null}}}, {{{Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, 
Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}}, {{Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}}, {{Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Subscript[p, 2, 2] Subscript[p, 4, 2]}, {Null,
 Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}}}, {{{Null, Null, Null}, {Null, 
Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}}, {{Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}}, {{Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3, 2\), \(2\)]\)}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}}}, {{{Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}}, {{Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}}, {{Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Subscript[p, 2, 2] Subscript[p, 4, 2]}, {Null,
 Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null,
 Null}}}, {{{Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}}, {{Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}}, {{Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Subscript[p, 1, 2] Subscript[p, 5, 2]}, {Null,
 Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null,
 Null}, {Null, Null, Null}}}, {{{Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}}, {{Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, 
Null}}, {{Null, Null, 
Subscript[p, 0, 2] Subscript[p, 6, 2]}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null,
 Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null, Null}, {Null, Null,
 Null}, {Null, Null, Null}}}}
```

We can spot some polynomials in this big table of NULL's which satisfy this property.

Question: How do I get rid of all these NULL's and only get the polynomials I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways.  You can return [`Nothing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) instead of the default `Null`.

```
polynomials = 
  Table[
    If[i + k == 6 && j + l == 4, 
      Subscript[p, i, j]*Subscript[p, k, l],
      Nothing
    ], 
    {i, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 10}, {k, 0, 10}, {l, 0, 10}]
```

This preserves the nested structure so you may want to [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html).

In old versions use `Unevaluated@Sequence[]` instead of `Nothing`.

You can also use [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html).

```
First@Last@Reap@Do[
  If[i + k == 6 && j + l == 4,
     Sow[Subscript[p, i, j]*Subscript[p, k, l]]
  ], 
  {i, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 10}, {k, 0, 10}, {l, 0, 10}
]
```

You can also use what you have and `polynomials /. Null -> Nothing` or `DeleteCases[polynomials, Null, Infinity]`.

Comment: If I use your first solution (and use Deletecases and Flatten to get rid of all the {}), I get some polynomials which occur more than once in the list. What should I do to get only 1 of such a polynomial?

Comment: @Badshah `DeleteDuplicates` or `Union`.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood aims, however, if it is to create the desired products you could use `MapIndexed` strictly at level 2, e.g.

```
left = DeleteCases[
  Flatten[MapIndexed[Boole[Total@(#2 - {1, 1}) == 6] HoldForm[#1] &, 
    variables, {2}]], 0]
right = DeleteCases[
  Flatten[MapIndexed[Boole[Total@(#2 - {1, 1}) == 4] #1 &, 
    variables, {2}]], 0]
products = Times @@@ Tuples[{left, right}]
```

Of  course you could use `Outer` and `Times`  or `Table` with list iterator etc.

Showing the result:

```
Grid[Partition[products, 7], Frame -> All]
```

[image]